# Ability to update texlive packages on ubuntu

Tags: latex, package-managers

I am using texlive on ubuntu and having issues with some packages used as they are too old. Downloading them from CTAN manually and installing fixes them but this is time consuming.

On windows we use Miktex and just update to all the latest packages.

Is there a way to update the packages in texlive to the latest from CTAN without going through the laborious process?

Comment: I think this will be migrated to superuser soon...

Comment: In re: moving to superuser. That depends. Should we move questions about fetching updates from CPAN to SuperUser too? This is the same problem. Search on "[perl] CPAN update" suggested that CPAN management is in, so I think that CTAN management should be too.

Comment: Have you tried using Ubuntu's package manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the command line: `sudo tlmgr update --all`

tlmgr is included in texlive 2008. it pretty nice. Pre-texlive 2008 (i.e., the one from the package manager) i can't help you.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered that the texlive in even the latest ubuntu (9.04) is pre texlive-2008. I am trying to install the latest textlive to see if this fixes my issues.

Comment: TeX Live 2008 is now frozen and packages won't be updated until TeX Live 2009 comes out (hopefully soon-ish).

Comment: on a side note... why are all the distros (by "all" i mean ubuntu and fedora, in my experience) using pre texlive2008? it has been out for a while...

Comment: Which package is this in? I can't find it.

Comment: Paul -- this is not a macro package. Its part of TeXLive 2008. Pre TexLive 2008 will not have this program.

Comment: I meant which ubuntu package. But I missed the bit where ubuntu 9.04 is missing texlive 2008, and so doesnt have it. Thanks.

Comment: www.tug.org has a slim install package for texlive 2008. it's a pretty easy install, i just did it yesterday on an xubuntu jaunty box. works well, and tlmgr is good.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added an [Ubuntu idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/22450). Please vote for it (or add a better solution) if you think that TeX Live should be updated to a newer distribution.

*I freely admit that this is not an immediate help, but given enough votes for the "Ubuntu idea" it might help in future releases - so I felt justified in posting it here. Please feel free to remove this "answer" if you think differently.*